# How do I use WSDL and implement a SOAP server in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have WSDL and XSD files and want implement a webservice based on this WSDL.

I've successfully installed the Action Web Service gem and it's worked without problem for me, but I really need it to use my custom WSDL and not one generated by ActionWebService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an answer for you, but it sounds like you need a code generator like wsdl2ruby available in the SOAP4R gem.

Here is a recent fork/update to SOAP4R: https://github.com/mumboe/soap4r

And there are a couple of examples of using SOAP4R to generate web service clients:

http://www.winstonyw.com/2008/09/02/howto-use-ruby-soap4r/

http://mrfrosti.com/tag/wsdl2ruby/

I haven't easily found any examples of generating server-side code, but wsdl2ruby seems to have a switch to perform that function.

Good luck.